# Java библиотека LWJGL: Display cannot be resolved

Tags: java, lwjgl

Скачал библиотеку LWJGL, мне необходимо добиться открыть "экран для реализации 3D". Для этого я добавил библиотеку в проект (импортировал в Build Path). Сделал всё, как написано [здесь](http://wiki.lwjgl.org/wiki/LWJGL_Basics_5_(Fullscreen)). Но, к сожалению, у меня вылетает ошибка.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Display cannot be resolved
    DisplayMode cannot be resolved to a type
    Display cannot be resolved
    Display cannot be resolved
```

Вот код класса:

```
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;

public class Screen {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(800, 600));
        Display.setFullscreen(true);
        Display.create();
}
```

Работаю в среде программирования Eclipse.

Comment: новая версия как 3.1.2 или 3.1.1 Display и DisplayMode уже удалены....

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо добавить в External JARs (Build Path) не только `lwjgl.jar`, но и `lwjgl_util.jar`. Затем, обязательно добавить Native Libraries (Файлы DLL, такие как `OpenAL.dll`, `jinput-dx8`), которые есть в архиве LWJGL, который я скачал с официального сайта.

---

Если работать не будет, то необходимо добавить код:

```
System.setProperty("java.build.path", str);
```

где строчка str - полный путь к директории с Native Libraries.